# How to retrieve number of attachments to FBO

Tags: opengl, fbo

How can I get number of color attachments to currently bind FBO? I checked `glGetInteger` and `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv` but they don't have enum to get these values.

Comment: ... Don't you know? I mean, it's *your* FBO, isn't it?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am using external library which has setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but this should do it:

```
GLint maxAtt = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS, &maxAtt);
int nAtt = 0;
for (int iAtt = 0; iAtt < maxAtt; ++iAtt) {
    GLint objType = GL_NONE;
    glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(
        GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + iAtt,
        GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE, &objType);
    if (objType != GL_NONE) {
        ++nAtt;
    }
}
// nAtt is the number of color attachments.
```

You could do something similar using `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_NAME` instead of `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE`, and comparing the value to `0`.